# Android : Click exits screen when selecting an item from an option list

Tags: android, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking at an option list on an android device
The options code looks like this:

```
<div class = "addMode">
 <label for ="activityType">Activity Type</label>
 <div class="dataRow activityType">
  <select id="activityType" class="valid">
   <option value ="1" selected="selected">Appointment</option>
   <option value ="2">Call</option>
   <option value ="3">To-Do</option>
  </select>
 </div>
<div>
```

At first I tried xpath:

```
el = @d.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[@id='activityType']/option")
el.each do |t|
   if t.text() == 'Call' then
      t.click
      break
   end
end
```

This works to select the 'Call' activity from the pop-up menu, however, as soon as it is selected it exits from the current page, and returns to the calling page.

I then tried:

```
el = @d.find_element(:id, "activityType")
el.click 
el_opt = el.find_elements(:tag_name, "option")
el_opt.each.do |t|
   if t.text() == 'Call' then
       t.click
       break
   end
end
```

This also had the same result of making the selection, and then exiting the screen

Then it was on to:

```
opt = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@d.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='activityType']"))
opt.select_by(:text, "Call")
```

This also made the selection, and then exited the page

I then thought, i might be able to use the Touch action
I'm still new to Ruby and I'm most likely reading the API for TouchScreen incorrectly
I tried the following:

```
TapObject = Selenium::WebDriver::TouchScreen.new(@d.find_element(:id, "activityType"))
el = @driver.find_element(:id, "activityType")
el_opt = el.find_elements(:tag_name, "option")
el_opt.each do |t|
  if t.text() == "Call" then
      TapObject.single_tap(t)
  end
end
```

I get an undefined method 'touchSingleTap' error for this

Has anyone run into this problem, or know of a way to click/tap on a selection on a mobile device without it exiting the current page?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution to this was really simple.
Instead of trying to click the element from the pop-up list, just use send keys instead.

```
el = @driver.find_element(:id, "activityType")
el.send_keys("Call")
```

Thanks,

Jeff